# What are good resources if I want to develop RSS feed readers for N97 and E71?

Tags: rss, symbian, nokia, e71, n97

What are good resources if I want to develop RSS feed readers for N97, E71 and other Symbian phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/) for questions and [this wiki](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php) for more getting started guides and code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a further set of links in this stackoverflow question:

[How to get started with Symbian (S60 plattorm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541613/how-to-get-started-with-symbian-s60-plattorm)