# start up tutorials for symbian development

Tags: java, mobile, symbian

I am a newbie wants to start symbian development. Can any body show me the path

1) from where to start
2) How to set up development enviornment.

Kindly  shed some light on this.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: You might want to read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541613/how-to-get-started-with-symbian-s60-plattorm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to developer for Symbian. The traditional native SDK is Symbian C++/S60, for which a good starting point is [here](http://developer.symbian.org/main/create_applications/index.php).

The Symbian world is moving rapidly to Qt as the native toolkit, so you might want to choose that route. There is a [Qt Quick Start](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Qt_Quick_Start) for that.

And then there is WRT, Python and Java ME as other options. All are described at the [Symbian Developer site](http://developer.symbian.org).